# How to remove Accordion gap when expanded?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, overriding, accordion

I'm trying to have the `Accordion` MUI component NOT move and NOT apply top and bottom margins to some elements while it is in the expanded mode.

Example follows like this, but it's not working, my component is still too "jumpy" (when expanded it increases in width and like some invisible margins are being added)

```
...
expanded: {
  margin: '0px',
},
test: {
  '&$expanded': {
    margin: '0px',
  },
},
...
<Accordion
  classes={{
    root: classes.test,
    expanded: classes.expanded,
  }}
  expanded={expanded}
>
  <AccordionSummary
    onClick={() => setExpanded(!expanded)}
    classes={{
      expanded: classes.expanded,
    }}
  >
    The Summary
  </AccordionSummary>
  <AccordionDetails>
    <p>the details</p>
  </AccordionDetails>
</Accordion>
```

Answer (score 20):

In MUI v5, it's as easy as setting `disableGutters` to `true`. This prevents all up/down repositioning when expanding the Accordion. More info here: https://mui.com/material-ui/api/accordion/#props.

Like this:

```js
<Accordion disableGutters>
  {/* ... */}
</Accordion>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do that by setting the `Accordion` margin to `auto` which should be the same as setting it to `0`. Make sure the style is applied to every `Accordion`s on the screen. See this example [here](https://material-ui.com/components/accordion/#customized-accordions).

The `Accordion` is being moved when expanding is just a side effect of positive margin plus the transition effect when expanded. Removing the margin will likely fix your issue.

```js
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import MuiAccordion from "@material-ui/core/Accordion";
import AccordionSummary from "@material-ui/core/AccordionSummary";
import AccordionDetails from "@material-ui/core/AccordionDetails";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

const Accordion = withStyles({
  root: {
    "&$expanded": {
      margin: "auto"
    }
  },
  expanded: {}
})(MuiAccordion);
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 66816785/how-to-make-accordion-expanded-state-steady]

Answer (score 0):

If people are still struggling with it, write a div or Box and wrap it around each accordion.
Example:

```
    
export const AccordionStyled = styled(Accordion)(
  sx({
    border: 'none',
    boxShadow: 'none',
  })
);

export const BoxStyled = styled(Box)(
  sx({
    '& AccordionStyled': {
      margin: '0px !important',
    },
  })
);

<BoxStyled>
 <AccordionStyled>
   [your code here]
 </AccordionStyled>
<BoxStyled>
```

This overrides margin and also helps control/remove any other styles applied by default. This also works for any MUI component that people find hard to remove or override.